# How to call exception in SQL sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How to call exception for case if row was not found:

```
analys = Analyzes.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
```

I attempted to o this:

```
try:
   analys = Analyzes.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
except NoResultFound as e:
     return Response(str(e), status=400, mimetype='application/json')
```

It does not work for me...

Also I tried this:

```
if analys.count() == 0:
   raise NameError('Protocol was not found!')
```

Comment: Use `one()` instead of `first()`, and read the tutorial: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#returning-lists-and-scalars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `.first()` doesn't return anything, `analys` will be `None`, which you can treat as False, so:

```
analys = Analyzes.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
if not analys:
    # We didn't get anything
    raise NameError("Protocol was not found")
```

Or, as Ilja Everilä mentioned-- you could use `.one` if you expect only ever one result.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import NoResultFound

try:
    analys = Analyzes.query.filter_by(id=id).one()
except NoResultFound:
    print('Oh Noes!')
```